# Generate a custom GRID & Zonal statistics for the given Geometry in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, zonal-statistics

What are the ways to generate a Custom GRID (Ex: 100m x 100m) in Google Earth Engine for a given extent.

Once the GRID is generated how to populate zonal statistics for the same GRID using any raster image?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this connected to QGIS, when you are trying to achieve it in GEE? Also, please refrain from asking two questions at once, since this makes answering and/or finding the correct answer afterwards harder.

Comment: I haven't tried anything related to this, as this is one of my requirements I would like to know any scope for this task in Google Earth Engine.

Comment: Have you tried using any search engine to get a general idea of the workflow?